# Can we use Firebase database with Laravel? What are the pros and cons?

Tags: database, laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am planning to build a web application along with iOS and Android apps. Someone suggested to go with Laravel.

Can I use Firebase with Laravel?
If yes what are the pros and cons?

Comment: can you mark answered please

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is a client-side framework so it is completely independent of your server side code. That said, the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) does not support PHP so if you need to use features of the admin SDK, you would be out of luck.